# Extract data outside of parentheses in oracle

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

I have this value: (203)1669

My requirement is to extract data which is outside of the parentheses.

I want to use Regular expression for this Oracle query.

Much appreciated!

Comment: any attempts in getting your wishes?

Comment: Is the pattern same always. I mean can you ever get something like `123(456)`

Comment: Hi @Utsav pattern is always the same. (203)XXXX

Comment: @Shikha - Ok. For the pattern you mention, see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34585826/5234334). I have added `trim` for precaution. You can remove it if you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Oracle `REGEXP_REPLACE()` function, and match the group which is outside the parentheses.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(phone_number, '\([[:digit:]]+\)(.*)', '\1') AS newValue
FROM your_table
```

Comment: think, you may try this also `(phone_number, '.*[^[:digit:]](.*)', '\1')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the combination of SUBSTR and INSTR function.

```
select substr('(203)1669', instr('(203)1669',')')+1) from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

This example uses REGEXP_SUBSTR() and the REGEX explicitly follows your spec of getting the 4 digits between the closing paren and the end of the line. If there could be a different number of digits, replace the `{4}` with a `+` for one or more digits:

```
SQL> with tbl(str) as (
      select '(203)1669' from dual
    )
    select regexp_substr(str, '\)(\d{4})$', 1, 1, NULL, 1) nbr
    from tbl;

NBR
----
1669

SQL>
```

Answer (score -1):

For the pattern you mentioned, this should work.

```
select  
rtrim(ltrim(substr(phone_number,instr(phone_number,')')+1,length(phone_number)))) 
as derived_phone_no
from 
(select '(123)456' as phone_number from dual union all
 select '(567)99084' as phone_number from dual)
```

Here first I am getting position of `)` and then getting `substr` from the position of `)` `+` `1` till the length of the string. As a best practice, you can use trim functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing quick solution!